# JSF page called from Servlet blank on first test on Tomcat 7

Tags: jsf, tomcat, servlets, jsf-2

Although I crawled through [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26408546/jsf-pages-shows-blank-when-deployed-on-tomcat-7) [four](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237224/blank-page-in-jsf-page) [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24092812/jsf-page-displays-blank-values-on-first-load) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112946/jsf-returns-blank-unparsed-page-with-plain-raw-xhtml-xml-el-source-instead-of-re), I still only get a blank page when the first JSF page I created within my servlet is called. It is deployed via IntelliJ IDEA on a Tomcat 7 server. On Error Log level "all", I don't get any error messages. The source code in the browser stays completely empty. It seems like FacesServlet isn't invoked, but IMO it can't be due to the url-mapping, it seems OK to me!??
Is there any other possibility, also as for looking into an error log?

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>incomingURLs</param-name>
        <param-value>http://localhost:8080,http://localhost:63342,https://localhost:63342</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_VIEW_MAPPINGS</param-name>
        <param-value>*.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Diagapp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.brainsee.diagapp.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <multipart-config>
            <location>/tmp</location>
            <max-file-size>20848820</max-file-size>
            <max-request-size>418018841</max-request-size>
            <file-size-threshold>1048576</file-size-threshold>
        </multipart-config>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Diagapp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/diagapp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Logoff</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.brainsee.diagapp.Logoff</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Logoff</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/logoff</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.brainsee.diagapp.LoginFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/diagapp/admin</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

diagnosesedit.xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<h:head>
    <title>Diagnoseeditor</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h3>Diagnosen</h3>
    <h:form rendered="#{not empty diagnosisBean.list}">
        <h:dataTable value="#{diagnosisBean.list}" var="diagnosis">
            <h:column><f:facet name="header">ID</f:facet>#{diagnosis.id}</h:column>
            <h:column><f:facet name="header">Text</f:facet>#{diagnosis.text}</h:column>
            <h:column><f:facet name="header">Alternativname</f:facet>#{diagnosis.altname}</h:column>
            <h:column><f:facet name="header">2. Alternativname</f:facet>#{diagnosis.altname2}</h:column>
            <h:column><f:facet name="header">ICD-10</f:facet>#{diagnosis.icd10}</h:column>
            <h:column><f:facet name="header">Alpha-ID</f:facet>#{diagnosis.alphaid}</h:column>
            <h:column><h:commandButton value="edit" action="#{diagnosisBean.edit(diagnosis)}" /></h:column>
            <h:column><h:commandButton value="delete" action="#{diagnosisBean.delete(diagnosis)}" /></h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
    </h:form>
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{empty diagnosisBean.list}">
        <p>Table is empty! Please add new diagnoses.</p>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{!diagnosisBean.edited}">
        <h3>Add diagnosis</h3>
        <h:form>
            <p>Value: <h:inputText value="#{diagnosisBean.diagnosis.value}" /></p>
            <p><h:commandButton value="add" action="#{diagnosisBean.add}" /></p>
        </h:form>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{diagnosisBean.edited}">
        <h3>Edit diagnosis #{diagnosisBean.diagnosis.id}</h3>
        <h:form>
            <p>Value: <h:inputText value="#{diagnosisBean.diagnosis.value}" /></p>
            <p><h:commandButton value="save" action="#{diagnosisBean.save}" /></p>
        </h:form>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:body>
</html>
```

It's called in my DispatcherServlet just with

```
response.sendRedirect("admin/diagnosesedit.xhtml");
```

from a jsp file which is in the same directory.

WEB-INF/faces-config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config version="2.2" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>diagnosisBean</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>com.brainsee.diagapp.beans.DiagnosisBean</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
</faces-config>
```

And the DiagnosisBean:

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class DiagnosisBean implements Serializable {
    private List<Diagnosis> list;
    private Diagnosis diagnosis = new Diagnosis();
    private boolean edited;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        list = DiagnosisDAO.getAll();
    }

    public void add() {
        DiagnosisDAO.insert(diagnosis);
        diagnosis = new Diagnosis();
    }

    public void edit(Diagnosis diagnosis) {
        this.diagnosis = diagnosis;
        edited = true;
    }

    public void save() {
        DiagnosisDAO.update(diagnosis);
        diagnosis = new Diagnosis();
        edited = false;
    }

    public void delete(Diagnosis diagnosis) {
        DiagnosisDAO.delete(diagnosis);
    }

    public List<Diagnosis> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public Diagnosis getDiagnosis() {
        return diagnosis;
    }

    public boolean isEdited() {
        return edited;
    }
}
```

In my dependencies, Mojarra-1.2 and javax.faces:javax-faces-api:2.2 are included under the "Provided" scope (changing that to "compile" doesn't change anything).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

....ARRRRGH just looked into the [great JSF wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info) and saw that I was using Servlet 3.0 features, but had the outdated Mojarra-1.2 as a library. Updated the library and *voilà*, it WORKS. So RTFM :)